# How make a TRY CATCH drop

Tags: sql, sql-server, heidisql

I want get this object name

[image]

to make a drop of a constraint with that name

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Establecimientos 
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF__Estableci__proce__498EEC8D
```

where `DF__Estableci__proce__498EEC8D` is the name of the object with whom I have conflict

I need catch that error and replace my code for him automatically.

Comment: That is probably a very bad idea to just blindly start dropping constraints like this. This has all the signs of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Is for a one case. I just created a script for him execution in environment of develop, and i just made the script for:
1 .- Script execution for first time before installation.
2 .- Script execution in case of error and we need have to go back the changes in the database

Comment: Maybe better researched over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is check if there's a default constraint before dropping the column.

This query will return you the name of the default constraint that exists on the column you want to drop. Just replace the table name and column name for the one you want to drop.

```
select dc.name 
from sys.default_constraints dc
join sys.tables t on t.object_id=dc.parent_object_id
join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id and c.column_id=dc.parent_column_id
where t.name='YourTABLE'
and c.name='YourCOLUMN'
```

With this query, you will create the "DROP CONSTRAINT" and execute it for your table and column. Remember to do this before dropping the column.

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)

select @Query='ALTER TABLE '+ schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + dc.name 
from sys.default_constraints dc
join sys.tables t on t.object_id=dc.parent_object_id
join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id and c.column_id=dc.parent_column_id
where t.name='YourTABLE'
and c.name='YourCOLUMN'

exec sp_execute @Query
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Just return the column name "name" and no more

Comment: The column name "name" is the name of the constraint of your column. You use it to retrieve the name of the constraint and to script the DROP. I'll change the example to do this.

Comment: Still dosnt working. This what happens, when i execute your first code, in the column does not return anything. That is the problem

Comment: did you change the "where t.name='YourTABLE' and c.name='YourCOLUMN'" for yours? What version of SQL Server are you usign? Do the COLUMN you are searching for has a default on it?

Comment: Yes, i changed it. The version is 11.0.5058.0. And yes, the column has a default value

Comment: I am using SQL 2016, how about this syntax (taken from Microsoft Documentation) SELECT d.name
FROM sys.default_constraints AS d  
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c  
ON d.parent_object_id = c.object_id
AND d.parent_column_id = c.column_id  
WHERE d.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'SCHEMA.TABLE', N'U')  
AND c.name = 'COLUMN';